# Can pi cam with raspberry pi take pictures at car speed of 40KPH?

Tags: raspicam, picamera

If I attach a pi-cam at front of a car and want to take pictures of the road at car speed of 40KPH, can the pi-cam take clear pictures? And is there a way to constantly change the fps of picam depending on speed of the car?

Comment: It depends on how you define a clear picture and what is in view. A car driving in front of you will be reasonably clear, a car driving in the opposite direction most likely won't.

Comment: I want to take images of the road as I want to perform crack detection

Comment: Still, it depends on what kind of cracks and how sensitive you need this to be, and how/where you install the camera. I dare say there's no way to tell without trying.